# PowerBI DAX: Count several factors of variable without duplicating ID

Tags: substring, powerbi

I am facing the following problem for a couple of weeks and I couldn't find a solution yet. Any help will be appreciated.

To clarify the problem, suppose I have this table:

ID                       |             SOURCE

1                        |                s1

2                        |                s2

3                        |              s1,s2

I want to show this result in the dashboard

SOURCE                  |              COUNT

s1                      |                2

s2                      |                2

without duplicating the third row of my dataframe.

How can I do that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the smoothest solution but it gets the job done:

Create two custom columns:

```
CustomColumn_s1 = IF(
ISERROR(
    SEARCH("*s1*";Table1[SOURCE])
);
BLANK();
1)


CustomColumn_s2 = IF(
ISERROR(
    SEARCH("*s2*";Table1[SOURCE])
);
BLANK();
1)
```

Then create two measures to count the occurrence:

```
Count s1 = COUNT(Table1[CustomColumn_s1])

Count s2 = COUNT(Table1[CustomColumn_s2])
```

Comment: Tried the solution you proposed, but what I need as output is a table with 2 columns, Source and Count.